# How do I get Comment tokens from the Dart Analyzer Scanner?

Tags: parsing, dart, tokenize

I'm using the tokeniser from the [Dart Analyzer package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/analyzer), starting with the code in [this example](https://github.com/dart-lang/bleeding_edge/blob/master/dart/pkg/analyzer/example/parser_driver.dart).

I've tweaked the code to just spit out the tokens (not using Parser) to try and track down my issue. So my code looks like this:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:analyzer/src/generated/ast.dart';
import 'package:analyzer/src/generated/error.dart';
import 'package:analyzer/src/generated/parser.dart';
import 'package:analyzer/src/generated/scanner.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {

  // Dummy code to parse (contains comments!)
  var src = """
               // test
               /* test */
               import 'dartd:io';
               // This is a test
  """;

  // Tokenise the code
  var errorListener = new _ErrorCollector();
  var reader = new CharSequenceReader(src);
  var scanner = new Scanner(null, reader, errorListener);
  var token = scanner.tokenize();

  // Dump all tokens to screen
  while (token != null && token.type != TokenType.EOF)
  {
    print(token);
    token = token.next;
  }
```

However, when I run this, the comments are gone:

```dart
import
'dartd:io'
;
```

I'm digging through the [Scanner code](https://github.com/dart-lang/bleeding_edge/blob/master/dart/pkg/analyzer/lib/src/generated/scanner.dart) trying to understand where the comments go, with no joy. There's a boolean called `_preserveComments` but it defaults to true anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comments seem to be in their own Token chain. You can access them through a normal Token's `precedingComments` accessor, and then you need to walk through each comment using `next` until you reach the end:

```dart
// Dump all tokens to screen
while (token != null && token.type != TokenType.EOF)
{
  printComments(token);
  print(token);
  token = token.next;

  if(token.type == TokenType.EOF) {
    printComments(token);
  }
}
```

```dart
void printComments(Token token) {
  var comments = token.precedingComments;
  while(comments != null) {
    print(comments);
    comments = comments.next;
  }
}
```

Comment: Aha! Great! Though this is booth good and bad... If they are included, that means there must be some similar trick to getting them in the AST - I assumed it was because they were missing from the tokens!